# Error Loading Pickle file from another system

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

We have a model being developed on a notebook, and looking to load it in a yarn cluster.  We are saving the model as a pickle file.  When loading the pickle file I am getting an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._philox import Philox
  File "_philox.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random._philox
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 404, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
TypeError: 'errstate' object is not callable
```

Both the cluster and notebook are running python 3.7.9 and running numpy 1.19.5, so it shouldn't be a versioning issue.

Edit:

```
from smart_open import open
import joblib

with open('s3://location/impute_jl.pkl', 'rb') as file:
      imputer_model = joblib.load(file)
```

I have also tried:

```
from smart_open import open
import pickle as pick

with open('s3://location/impute_jl.pkl', 'rb') as file:
      imputer_model = pick.load(file)
```

Comment: Please post code that generates this error.

Comment: updated the original post with code that caused the error.

Comment: do you have all imports used to save the object to pickle imported at the point you are loading the pickle?